# Link stylesheet to ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, stylesheet

I want to know if there is a solution to achieve something like this, where a stylesheet, only styles a part of the page.

```
<link href="/Content/stylesheet.css" for="OnlyApplyStylesWithinHere" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<div id="OnlyApplyStylesWithinHere">
</div>
```

I know that i can do this from within the stylesheet itself, but that is not possible in my scenario.

Can this effect be done with Javascript/Jquery maybe?

Comment: possible duplicate of [making different syle sheets apply to different areas of the page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441999/making-different-syle-sheets-apply-to-different-areas-of-the-page)

Comment: I sugggest you to declare the css to specify to only child of **#OnlyApplyStylesWithinHere** to work only child of its, like `#ApplyStyle .child` will work with only **child's class tag** in **ApplyStyle's id**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made this plugin witch does what you want, if the stylesheet dosn't break the [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript).

**You can use it like this:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="..." data-wrapper="#mySelector" />

<style data-wrapper="#mySelector">
    .ninja { 
        visibility: hidden;
    }
</style>
```

**And again after initialize:**

```
$("link[rel='stylesheet']").addWrapperToStyle("#mySelector");

$("style").addWrapperToStyle("#mySelector");
```

---

```
    (function($) {
        var $styleSheet = $("<style type='text/css'/>").appendTo("head");

        function getStyle( $element, callback ) {
            callback($element.text());
        }
        function getLink( $element, callback ) {
            $.get($element.attr("href"), function( style ) {
                callback(style);
            });
        }
        function appendStyle( style ) {
            $styleSheet.text(function(i, text) {
                return text + "\n" + style;
            });
        }

        function wrapStyle( element, selector ) {
            var $element = $(element);

            if ( $element.is("style") ) {
                getStyle( $element, callback );
            } else {
                getLink( $element, callback );
            }

            function callback( style ) {
                if ( style ) {
                    style = ("" + style).replace(/([^}]+){/g, function(match) {
                        var matches = match.split(","),
                            i = 0,
                            len = matches.length;

                        for ( ; i < len; i++ ) {
                            matches[i] = selector + " " + $.trim(matches[i])
                        }

                        match = matches.join(",");

                        return match;
                    });

                    appendStyle(style);

                    $element.remove();
                }
            }
        }

        $(function() {
            $("link[rel='stylesheet'][data-wrapper], style[data-wrapper]").each(function() {
                wrapStyle( this, this.getAttribute("data-wrapper") );
            });
        });
        $.fn.addWrapperToStyle = function( wrapper ) {
            return this.each(function() {
                wrapStyle(this, wrapper);
            });
        } 
    })(jQuery);
```

**Im not sure about cross browser compatibility. But you can try...**

Comment: Wow this is great! I will test this later today and give you an update with the browser compatibility!

Comment: @BjarkeCK - Whats the status on browser compatibility?

Answer (score 1):

There is a HTML5 feature for this called [scoped stylesheets](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/03/A-New-Experimental-Feature-style-scoped); it is [part](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/semantics.html#attr-style-scoped) of the WHATWG draft, but browser support is nonexistent (Chrome supports it via `about:flags`, but there is no out-of-the-box support). You can use [this javascript plugin](https://github.com/thingsinjars/jQuery-Scoped-CSS-plugin) to make it work.

Alternatively, if server-side rewrite of the stylesheet is possible, you can use something like [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/):

```
#my-section {
    @import "local-copy-of-the-stylesheet.scss";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if media attribute helps you. media="handheld" will not define css only for apple but for all small screen device.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_link_media.asp

Answer (score 0):

we can put styles in 3 ways,

```
1)Internal
```

put all your styles inside the same html page, withing style tag

```
2)External
```

by giving reference for the stylesheet at head section, in html page

```
3)In-line
```

this can be done using style attribute for the html element
i,e. `<div style="some styles"></div>`

i think anyone of the above can solve your doubt.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe what you are requesting is possible.

However one *hacky* method would be to put this HTML markup into a seperate file, with the stylesheet linked in the `head` and then include this in your original file using an `iframe`.

```
<head>
   <link href="[main stylesheet" />
   <link href="[this page only stylesheet]" />
</head>
```

Like I say, its hacky, but I think its the only approach without changing the stylesheet.